# Regex in Where Linq ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, linq

I wanted to know if it was possible to use a Regex rule in a linq request.
Indeed I would like to know if an ID contains the word "Download".

Test 1:

```
foreach (var apiData in viewReturn.Where(x => x.ID.Contains("Download")))
  {
    apiExterne.Add(apiData);
  }
```

This format works

Test 2:

```
foreach (var apiData in viewReturn.Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x.ID, "^[dD][oO][wW][nN][lL][oO][aA][dD]$")))
  {
    apiExterne.Add(apiData);
  }
```

This one does not work.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: And what does "does not work" mean? Does it not find a match? Do you get an error?

Comment: Hello @Space and welcome to SO ! What do you mean by "This one does not work". Could you please elaborate your exact question, and detail the error you encounter ? Also you may be interested in the [how to ask documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Have you tried simplifying - Where(x => x != nulll && Regex.IsMatch(x.ID.ToUpper(), "DOWNLOAD"))) - and remove the anchors if you only want to check if it contains the word download

Answer (score 3):

Adding `^` and `$` characters to the start and end of the regex means that the entire string should match, not just a substring. So technically your regex is not equivalent to `Contains()` function, which would return true for substring match too.

Remove those two characters from your substring. Also you do not need both upper and lower case letters, instead you can use `IgnoreCase` option.

You should not use regex for such a simple scenarios. If the only reason you're using Regex is that your string could use any combination of upper and lower cases, check [this excellent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring) for a `Contains()` function that can ignore case for you. Alternately, you could also call `ToLower()` in your LINQ:

```
foreach (var apiData in viewReturn.Where(x => x.ID.ToLower().Contains("download")))
```

Answer (score 2):

You used anchors, `^` (start of string) and `$` (end of string), that require a *full string match*. Also, there is no need using character classes listing all letter cases, use the [case insensitive regex flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.ignorecase?view=netframework-4.7).

If you want to use a regex use

```
foreach (var apiData in viewReturn.Where(x => 
          Regex.IsMatch(x.ID, "download", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)))
{
   apiExterne.Add(apiData);
}
```

**A non regex solution is considered the best approach**:

```
foreach (var apiData in viewReturn.Where(x => 
          culture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(x, "download", CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) >= 0))
{
   apiExterne.Add(apiData);
}
```

See [this SO thread for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15464440/3832970).

Answer (score -1):

As explained in the [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-combine-linq-queries-with-regular-expressions), this is what you should do:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex searchTerm =  
        new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^[dD][oO][wW][nN][lL][oO][aA][dD]$");  
var queryMatching =  
        from item in viewReturn  
        let itemID = item.ID  
        let matches = searchTerm.Matches(itemID)  
        where matches.Count > 0  
        select new  
        {  
            id = item.ID,  
            apiData = from System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match in matches  
                            select match.Value  
        };
```